# warning: passing 'int *[10]' to parameter of type 'const int *const *' discards qualifiers in nested pointer types

Tags: c

I have the following file `aaa.c`:

```
int Test(const int * const * int_array, int count) {
  int min = int_array[0][0];
  for (int i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
    if (min > int_array[i][0])
      min = int_array[i][0];
  }
  return min;
}

void test_Test(void) {
  int i[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  int *pi[10] = { &i[0], &i[1], &i[2], &i[3], &i[4], &i[5],
    &i[6], &i[7], &i[8], &i[9] };
  Test(pi, 10);
}
```

When I compile it with `gcc -c aaa.c`, the following warning is produced:

```
% gcc -c aaa.c 
aaa.c: In function ‘test_Test’:
aaa.c:14:8: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Test’ from incompatible pointer type 
        [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   Test(pi, 10);
        ^~
aaa.c:1:5: note: expected ‘const int * const*’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
 int Test(const int * const * int_array, int count) {
     ^~~~
```

Why? What qualifier was discarded? `const int * const * int_array` certainly doesn't discard any qualifiers that `int **` would have.

Comment: Notice the tags! You've tagged both  [tag:c] and [tag:c++] - that is **incorrect**, the question is solely about **c**.

Comment: How did you compile if I may to ask and which compiler ?

Comment: @CIsForCookies ack.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, Yes, you are right.

Comment: @TonyTannous, I compile it with gcc.

Comment: I have seen the suggested answer of the similar question.So it's a bug of c standard?